# indefinite integral of inverse trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

How can we integrate the following
I am unable to find a suitable method or formula by which i can get the value of this integral.

$$ \int {\sqrt{\cot^{-1} x}} + {\sqrt{\tan^{-1} x}} \, dx$$

Comment: It seems difficult, even [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28arccot+x%29+%2B+sqrt%28arctan+x%29) couldn't answer it.

Comment: $404$ Answer Not Found. :D

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki Since when $\text{arccot }x+\arctan x=\pi$??

Comment: Since $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cot(x)$, he really means $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I made a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Using $${\cot^{-1} x}+\tan^{-1}x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

We obtain
$$\int\sqrt{\cot^{-1} x}+\sqrt{\tan^{-1} x}dx=\int\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} x}+\sqrt{\tan^{-1} x}dx$$

Let $x=\tan{\theta}$, $\phi=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta$, then we can simplify:
$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta}+\sqrt{\theta}}{\cos^2{\theta}}d\theta=-\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\phi}}{\sin^2{\phi}}d\phi+\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$$

Let $\theta = \psi^2$ and just calculate the second part of the right side because of its resemblance with another one:
$$\int\dfrac{2\psi^2}{\cos^2\psi^2}d\psi=[\psi \tan \psi^2]-\int\tan\psi^2 d\psi$$

I looked for indefinite integration of $\tan x^2$ in Internet, but I found no answer. It indicates that this part makes the desired integration impossible without numerical analysis.